# installing Watir using ruby installer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

im trying to install Watir framework in my Windows 64 bit machine and it gives me this error

```
 Error installing watir:
 rautomation requires ffi (= 1.9.0, runtime)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try manually installing the rautomation or even the ffi game.  Watir depends on them.

gem install rautomation

Comment: i did this it works now but another error displays  gems/watir-5.0.0-x86-mingw32/lib/watir/loader.rb:45: stack level too deep (SystemStackError) .. any idea?